# Java API for rendering 2D and 3D interactive graphics (Javaview substitute)

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, 2d

I will teach a course on Computer Graphics, and want a Java library that creates 2D and 3D interactive graphics based on math models (points, areas, lines).

The last one I used was Javaview, back in 2007, but I think it relies on Java applets, which are no longer supported by Java 11.

I want recommendations for something new and easy to install and to use, and it has to be in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Java 2D API?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/spec/j2d-intro.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/

Comment: Thanks, will try. But I prefer something iterative, that rotates, have zoom in/out, and be 3D too.